# AngularJs - $http.get is not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Unable to get data from PHP file.

php

```
require 'dbconnect.php';

$array_data = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($array_data);
$result_data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

if( !empty($result_data) ) {    

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $json = json_encode($result_data);
    // echo $json;
    echo preg_replace("/null/", '""', $json); // replace null to ""

}
```

controller.js

```
.controller('tableCtrl', function($filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {

        var data = tableService.data
    //Editable
        this.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10           // count per page
        }, {
            total:data.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
    })
```

script.js

```
.service('tableService', ['$http', function($http){

        this.data = $http.get("data/timesheet.json")

    }])
```

html

```
<table ng-table="tctrl.tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
       <tr ng-repeat="w in $data"  ng-class="{ 'active': w.$edit }">
          <td data-title="'ID'">
             <span ng-if="!w.$edit">{{ w.id }}</span>
             <div ng-if="w.$edit"><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="w.id" /></div>
          </td>
          ...
       </tr>                        
   </table>
```

When I put json data in service.js like this.data = [{..}] it's working but now I'm just trying to pull data from php file which is not working and getting blank table. Can any one help me that what is missing here? I am very new to AngularJS.

Comment: " trying to pull data from php" - no, you are pulling data from some json

Comment: can you show us how the data is coming back from the php file. I would suggest this isn't an Angular issue.

Comment: @defaultcheckbox Sorry but I didn't get your question. I have added my php code. And yes I have tried json file which contain static json data but having same issue with that also

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
.service('tableService', ['$http', function($http){
  this.data = $http.get("yourphpfile.php");
}])
```

then

```
.controller('tableCtrl', function ($filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {
    this.tableEdit = {};
    tableService.data.then(initNgTable);

    function initNgTable(data) {
        this.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
                page : 1, // show first page
                count : 10 // count per page
            }, {
                total : data.length, // length of data
                getData : function ($defer, params) {
                    $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
    }
})
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Did you debug? Where you saw the problem?

Comment: User7.. can you just show us the format of the json? or maybe doing a plunker with dummy json. I don't think we have enough info to figure out what's wrong.